# Error in PayPal Chained Adaptive Payments

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

After two days of testing, googling and so on, I decided to write here. I'm sorry for my bad English :)

I downloaded the **PayPal Adaptive Payments SDK** for **.NET** from http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#adaptive-payments and I opened the solution with **Visual Studio Ultimate 2012** to try the samples. Unfortunately the Chained example doesn't works, with the following error:

> Invalid request parameter: action type PAY_PRIMARY can only be used in chained payments

I studied documentation and tried several changes, without any result.

I created new project with this code https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_chained_payment/dotnet?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

My code is

```
        ReceiverList receiverList = new ReceiverList();

        receiverList.receiver = new List<Receiver>();

        Receiver secondaryReceiver = new Receiver((decimal?)1.00);
        secondaryReceiver.email = "platfo_1255170694_biz@gmail.com";
        secondaryReceiver.primary = false;
        secondaryReceiver.paymentType = "SERVICE";
        receiverList.receiver.Add(secondaryReceiver);

        Receiver primaryReceiver = new Receiver((decimal?)2.00);
        primaryReceiver.email = "platfo_1255612361_per@gmail.com";
        primaryReceiver.primary = true;
        primaryReceiver.paymentType = "GOODS";
        primaryReceiver.invoiceId = "123456789";
        receiverList.receiver.Add(primaryReceiver);

        RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("it_IT");
        string actionType = "PAY";
        string returnUrl = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_chained_payment/dotnet?success=true";
        string cancelUrl = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_chained_payment/dotnet?cancel=true";
        string currencyCode = "EUR";
        PayRequest payRequest = new PayRequest(requestEnvelope, actionType, cancelUrl, currencyCode, receiverList, returnUrl);

        payRequest.ipnNotificationUrl = "http://replaceIpnUrl.com";

        payRequest.feesPayer = "PRIMARYRECEIVER";
        payRequest.trackingId = "123456789";

        Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        sdkConfig.Add("mode", "sandbox");
        sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiUsername", "jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com");
        sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiPassword", "WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F");
        sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiSignature", "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy");
        sdkConfig.Add("account1.applicationId", "APP-80W284485P519543T");

        AdaptivePaymentsService service = new AdaptivePaymentsService(sdkConfig);
        PayResponse response = service.Pay(payRequest);

        string redirectUrl = null;

        if (!response.responseEnvelope.ack.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals(AckCode.FAILURE.ToString()) && !response.responseEnvelope.ack.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals(AckCode.FAILUREWITHWARNING.ToString()))
        {
            redirectUrl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=" + response.payKey;
        }
```

I tried to set the property `feesPayer` to `PRIMARYRECEIVER` with the following error:

> The fee payer PRIMARYRECEIVER can only be used if a primary receiver is specified

The Request of this code is

```
requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=it_IT&
actionType=PAY
cancelUrl=https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_chained_payment/dotnet?cancel=true&
currencyCode=EUR&
feesPayer=PRIMARYRECEIVER&
ipnNotificationUrl=http://replaceIpnUrl.com&
receiverList.receiver(0).amount=1&
receiverList.receiver(0).email=platfo_1255170694_biz@gmail.com&
receiverList.receiver(0).primary=False&
receiverList.receiver(0).paymentType=SERVICE&
receiverList.receiver(1).amount=2&
receiverList.receiver(1).email=platfo_1255612361_per@gmail.com&
receiverList.receiver(1).primary=True&
receiverList.receiver(1).invoiceId=123456789&
receiverList.receiver(1).paymentType=GOODS&
returnUrl=https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_chained_payment/dotnet?success=true&
trackingId=123456789&
```

The Response is

```
responseEnvelope.timestamp=2014-05-08T09:05:04.204-07:00&
responseEnvelope.ack=Failure&
responseEnvelope.correlationId=1a4d172eb110d&
responseEnvelope.build=10680030&
error(0).errorId=580023&
error(0).domain=PLATFORM&
error(0).subdomain=Application&
error(0).severity=Error&
error(0).category=Application&
error(0).message=The fee payer PRIMARYRECEIVER can only be used if a primary receiver is specified&
error(0).parameter(0)=feesPayer&
error(0).parameter(1)=PRIMARYRECEIVER
```

The line `primaryReceiver.primary = true;` in my C# code seems not to work... any ideas please? Has anyone had this type of problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try changing "True" to "true" and see if that helps.  If not, I'd need to see a sample of the actual request getting generated instead of the code that is generating it.

Comment: I saw this little difference from true and True but I can't change it, because the request is generated from the SDK, and there isn't source code, only the DLLs.

The actual request is the Request that I have posted.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I downloaded the source code of the SDK and I changed primary parameter from True to true, and now it works!

Comment: So, is this fixed in the SDK now? Or will I need to fix the SDK myself instead of using NuGet? @AndrewAngell